# Is there a simpler way to check if a variable is `nil` or an empty array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a variable:

```
my_arr
```

which may be `nil` or an array. I would like to verify if it contains at least one element. It can be accomplished by:

```
my_arr && !my_arr.empty?
```

but I want to write it simpler. I tried:

```
!my_arr.empty?
```

but it fails if `my_arr` is `nil`. Is there a simple way?

Comment: There’s `my_arr&.empty? == false`, which is… not better. Also `(my_arr || []).empty?`, also not better. Just stick with what you have.

Comment: could array possibly contain `nil` and/or `false` values?

Comment: Just make sure that `my_arr` is always an array. Why should something that is supposed to be an array actually be `nil`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
my_arr.to_a.empty?
```

Because:

```
nil.to_a #=> []
```

An array instance on the other hand just returns itself.

The same "trick" works for other classes:

```
nil.to_h.empty? #=> true
nil.to_s.empty? #=> true
nil.to_i.zero?  #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use safe access operator and `any?` method in case your array can't possibly contain `nil` and `false` values:

```
my_arr&.any?
```

In case it can, you could use `any?(&:to_s)`, which seems neither native nor more elegant than your original solution.

Generally it is a better idea to be sure that it is always going to be an array, or at least something with the same duck type support.